# How to dock/lock "Highlight Properties" toolbar into main toolbar of Acrobat?

Tags: acrobat

I'm currently using Adobe Acrobat XI Pro with Windows 7.
By selecting `Ctrl + e` a floating 'Properties' toolbar appears. When I select highlighted text or the highlighter tool this advanced tools toolbar becomes a 'Highlight Properties' toolbar.

However, **I want to *dock* (aka lock) this toolbar into the main toolbar at the top of the Acrobat window** so that it's always there. **I can't figure out how to do this**.

Acrobat XI does now allow some modification of the main toolbar ribbon  at the top of the window (vs. Acrobat X), but I can't find where the "Highlight Properties' toolset is located in the toolbar customization window.

Comment: This toolbar is its own entity, and I am not aware that it can be docked to the main toolbars. You also have to be aware that its content changes depending on the object you have selected.

Comment: I understand the content changes. I was hoping since it *can* exist as a standalone toolbar that if he able to find it as an option to add to the main toolbar ribbon